# Searchview in listview like MX player

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, searchview

I am trying to implement a search view in a listview. I have 1 activity which has listview with folders having songs. In the searchview I am trying to search for the songs which can be present in any of the folders. I tried implementing Filterable but I am confused how this can be achieved. I know the regular searching using adapter and filter. But not the one like in MX player. Attaching the screenshot.[image]

As shown in the pic, search view is searching for the songs present in any of the folders.

Here is the code which I have tried :

Adapter class:

```
private ArrayList<VideosModel> videos;
private ArrayList<VideosModel> totalVideos;

public VideoHomeAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<VideosModel> video,ArrayList<VideosModel> totalVideo) {
    super();
    this.mContext = c;
    this.videos = video;
    this.glossariesListForSearch = totalVideo;
    this.totalVideos = totalVideo;




}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return videos.size();
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {

    return myFilter;
}

Filter myFilter = new Filter() {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
            FilterResults results) {
        if (results != null) {
        totalVideos = (ArrayList<VideosModel>) results.values;

            if (results.count > 0) {
            // no idea what to write here .
                // totalVideos is the list with all the videos 
            } else {

            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
        ArrayList<VideosModel> tempGlossaryList = new ArrayList<VideosModel>();

        if (constraint != null && glossariesListForSearch != null) {
            int length = glossariesListForSearch.size();

            int i = 0;
            while (i < length) {

                VideosModel item = glossariesListForSearch.get(i);
                // Real filtering:
                if (item.getVideoTitle()
                        .toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                        .contains(
                                constraint.toString().toLowerCase(
                                        Locale.getDefault()))) {
                    tempGlossaryList.add(item);
                }
                i++;
            }

            filterResults.values = tempGlossaryList;
            filterResults.count = tempGlossaryList.size();

        }
        return filterResults;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved it using AutoCompleteTextView instead of SearchView using this link :[AutoCompleteTextView](http://drzon.net/how-to-create-a-clearable-autocomplete-dropdown-with-autocompletetextview/)

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    ActionBar actionBar = getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar(); // you
                                                                        // can
                                                                        // use
                                                                        // ABS
                                                                        // or
                                                                        // the
                                                                        // non-bc
                                                                        // ActionBar
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM
            | ActionBar.DISPLAY_USE_LOGO | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME
            | ActionBar.DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP); // what's mainly important here
                                                // is DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM.
                                                // the rest is optional

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    // inflate the view that we created before
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.actionbar_search, null);
    final ImageView searchIcon = (ImageView) view
            .findViewById(R.id.search_icon);
    final ClearableAutoCompleteTextView searchBox = (ClearableAutoCompleteTextView) view
            .findViewById(R.id.search_box);

    // start with the text view hidden in the action bar
    searchBox.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    searchIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            toggleSearch(false, view);
        }
    });

    searchBox.setOnClearListener(new OnClearListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClear() {
            toggleSearch(true, view);
        }
    });

    searchBox.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // handle clicks on search results here

            Intent intent = new Intent(getSherlockActivity(),
                    SearchVideoResult.class);

            VideosModel model = searchAdapter.getItem(position);

            // intent.putExtra("folderPath",model.getFolderFullPath());
            intent.putExtra("videoId", model.getVideoId());
            startActivity(intent);
            searchBox.setText("");
            searchBox.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            searchIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        }

    });

    actionBar.setCustomView(view);
}
```